# Convert string by javascript date function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to initialize a new date object but I don't understand why returns me ever Invalid Date.

```
var dateString= this.get("created_at");
    var dataParts = dateString.split(' ');
    var timeParts = dataParts[3].split(':');

    //console.log(dataParts);-->["Fri", "May", "09", "17:45:54", "+0000", "2014"] 
    //console.log(timeParts);-->["17", "45", "54"]


    var year=dataParts[5];
    var month=dataParts[1];
    var day=dataParts[2];
    var hour=timeParts[0];
    var minute=timeParts[1];
    var second=timeParts[2];


    var date = new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,second);


    console.log(date);
```

Comment: ["Fri", "May", "09", "17:45:54", "+0000", "2014"] Should be ["Fri", "04", "09", "17:45:54", "+0000", "2014"]

Comment: Please [**read the documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters): *"`month` Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,second);
```

using this constructor the month needs to be a number, not "May".

Note also that months begin at 0 for January, so May is 4.

Alternatively, construct the date as a string: `new Date("May 09, 2014 17:45:54")` from the parts that you have. (You won't have to split the time or lookup the month-number.)

Comment: +1 - Small note, months should be 0 based, so May should be 4.

Comment: Could you tell me how convert may in appropriate number?

Comment: Use an `Object` as a lookup table. `{..., May: 4, ...}`